# Can I add a background to a <pre> on blogger?

Tags: css, blogger

what I want to do is to add a CSS background to a `<pre>`.

Is it posible to do it like this?

```
pre{
    background-color: EBECE4; 
}
```

or I need to do a little more?
I try like that but I did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes you can
but put color with "#"

```
pre{
    background-color: #EBECE4; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment (I forgot to add #) but this thas not work too.  Any idea?

Comment: @maniat1k, please post your code or a URL. Just saying “not work” does not help, when it is easy to see that it works, using a very simple test page.

Answer (score 5):

almost there:

```
pre{
    background-color: #EBECE4; 
}
```